# Calculate time difference between fields

Tags: sql, delphi

I am doing some time calculations in a TEMP table.
I have the following fields: `DATE_FROM,DATE_TO,TIME_FROM,TIME_TO`.
The fields are all DateTime.
To calculate the difference between `TIME_FROM` and `TIME_TO` I have added a calculated
field called `TIME_DIFFERENCE` which is also DateTime field.The database is absolute database. So on my TEMP's `oncalculate` fields event I have added:

```
procedure TForm1.TEMPCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
TEMP.Fields.FieldByName('TIME_DIFFERENCE').AsDateTime :=
          (TEMP.FieldByName('TIME_FROM').AsDateTime) - 
          (TEMP.FieldByName('TIME_TO').AsDateTime);
end;
```

Time difference works ok but I have run into a difficulty: The calculation only works between time fields. I don't know how to link the `TIME_FROM` to a `DATE_FROM` field. Because if I select `TIME_FROM` to be 22:00:00 and `TIME_TO` to be 06:00:00 I get the 16 hour difference (It should be 8). How can I accomplish this so my `TIME_FROM` starts from (with) the `DATE_FROM` ? And the end part as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql and also in Delphi a Date/DateTime variable/field contains a numeric value.

Suppose that the value is 1.0, then this represents 1 Day. 1.5 will represent 1 Day and 12 Hours.

So, when you put 22:00:00 into Time_From it will have a value of 22/24 in it. And if you put 6:00:00 to time_to the variable will have the value 06/24 when you subtract these you will get normally 16/24.

What I understand from your question is that you are asking for the difference of tonights 22:00 and 06:00 in the next morning. To have the right calculation you should add 1 day to Time_To variable. ( 06+24=30 ) 30/24.

And a small note, make the operation otherway round. Time-To - Time-From. Assuming that Time-From is in the past.

Comment: TEMP.FieldByName('TIME_TO').AsDateTime +24 is that what you mean?

Comment: Just add +1 for a single day (+24 would add 24 days)

Answer (score 0):

Write sql query where you calculate time difference.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, (TIME_FROM - TIME_TO) AS TIME_DIFFERENCE FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Comment: And what do you think I am trying to do ? :)

Comment: Maybe you need combine date and time `DATE_FROM + TIME_FROM` the calculate, OR using function in delphi [HourSpan](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.HourSpan) Or [HoursBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.HoursBetween)

Comment: combine date and time DATE_FROM + TIME_FROM the calculate - YES ...THAT'S WHAT i NEED.